# How do I used a Google web font as a SUBSTITUTE font?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use a Google web font as a substitute font.  But instead of being a substitute font, it is acting as a primary font.

In my , I have it linked to the font:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Balthazar' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

In my CSS, I have variations of the Copperplate font and I know it works on my PC and I have some of them installed.  This part is at the beginning of my CSS:

```
.class{
    font-size: 24pt;
    font-family: Copperplate Gothic Bold, Copperplate Gothic Light, Copperplate, Balthazar;
}
```

But even though Balthazar is the last font, it is coming up as the first.  Ho wo I fix ths?

Comment: What happens if you replace Balthazar with some distinctive font installed in your system, say Courier? If the text then appears in that font, then the issue is not connected with Google fonts; rather, none of the Copperplate fonts is recognized by the browser you are using (which?).

Answer (score 1):

font-family degradation appears to work just fine with Google font in all three of their import scenarios (`@import`, `<link>`, or `JavaScript`).

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/awRQm/

---

The most likely cause is that it really ***is*** falling back to Balthazar.

For multi-word font names, it's best to wrap them in single quotes like so:

```
.class{ font-size: 24pt; font-family: 'Copperplate Gothic Bold', 'Copperplate Gothic Light', Copperplate, Balthazar; }
```

According to the [CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-family-prop):

> "if a sequence of identifiers is given as a font family name, the
>   computed value is the name converted to a string by joining all the
>   identifiers in the sequence by single spaces"

Comment: No, the spec says “joining ... by single spaces”, so it just means that whitespace between words is collapsed to one space. Quotation marks are not the issue here.

Comment: I just tried putting them in quotation marks and unfortunately, the problem still occurs.  Copperplate Gothic Light is installed on my computer, but it is not showing.  I just see Balthazar font on my computer that has the Copperplate Gothic Light but not the Bold one.

Answer (score 1):

Fonts that have spaces in the name must be put in quotations in order to be read properly by css, this also goes for google web fonts, just to be on the safe side.

Example: `font:family: "Copperplate Gothic Bold", "Copperplate Gothic Light", Copperplate, "Balthazar";`